# RenderScript implementation of BLAS?

Tags: renderscript, blas

I've seen this: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/commit/35ef270f319aeac81d562897c480b507102dc9ae

And so I'm wondering when this will be available to the external 3rd party developers for general usage.  Any info would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Anthony

Comment: frankly , this should be voted up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already part of the M preview and will be in the forthcoming M SDK.

Comment: Awesome!  So...hahahah...no date on M eh?

Comment: I think we would both prefer that I keep my job (so I can answer more questions).

Comment: That's really awesome! But will it also be backported via some sort of compatibility library? I wonder if it would be feasible to just include the source as part of our own apps?

Comment: Err, it looks like it's part of the support library, so it should work on older versions when the appropriate release of support v8 comes out, right?

Comment: Oh huh, maybe it's already available in Support Library version 23? http://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/23/changes.html seems to imply so... if so, this is really cool!

Comment: Is the renderscript source for BLAS available? I haven't been able to find it yet. Thanks!

Comment: Check external/gemmlowp and external/cblas in AOSP. That should be what you are looking for, since RS is using those directly.