# Eigen library for Android NDK from GoogleSource

Tags: android, c++, gradle, android-ndk, eigen

I need Eigen C++ library to build my Android app.
So, I google and find a great library here
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/eigen

But, I don't know how to use this library, how to compile and include them into my project.

I'm using Android Studio with Grade-experimental 2.1.0

Anybody have experience about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it was part of the BLAS integration for Renderscript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620728/renderscript-implementation-of-blas

Comment: Yes, Can I use it in my project?

Comment: You might want to explain how you want to use Eigen or see if you can use the Renderscript BLAS functions which are in the Renderscript Support Library http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v8/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBLAS.html

Comment: Yes, thank you!
I want to use Eigen in my JNI code, too.

Comment: See this link [Eigen in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317701/add-eigen-library-to-android-ndk?noredirect=1#comment83628176_48317701)

Answer (score 0):

it migth be late for you but it could be useful for other developers. You can use Eigen headers (download them o the official site) and change CMakeList.txt to include them adding this line:
    `include_directories(path to Eigen headers)`


See this link for futher information:


[Eigen in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317701/add-eigen-library-to-android-ndk?noredirect=1#comment83628176_48317701)