# Add Eigen to android

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, eigen

Hello I'm having some issues trying to include [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) into my android ndk project.

This is the error message I get when trying to run the application:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build D:\newnativetest\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a --target native-lib}
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o 
C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe -target aarch64-none-linux-android -gcc-toolchain C:/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64  -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS -ID:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen -isystem C:/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem C:/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a/include -isystem C:/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -std=c++11 -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles\native-lib.dir\native-lib.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o -c D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:3:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Core:458:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:14:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/../../Eigen:1:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Dense:2:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/LU:28:
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/LU/FullPivLU.h:255:24: error: no member named 'rcond_estimate_helper' in namespace 'Eigen::internal'
      return internal::rcond_estimate_helper(m_l1_norm, *this);
             ~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:3:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Core:458:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:14:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/../../Eigen:1:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Dense:2:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/LU:29:
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:187:24: error: no member named 'rcond_estimate_helper' in namespace 'Eigen::internal'
      return internal::rcond_estimate_helper(m_l1_norm, *this);
             ~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:3:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Core:458:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:14:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/../../Eigen:1:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Dense:3:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Cholesky:32:
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Cholesky/LLT.h:165:24: error: no member named 'rcond_estimate_helper' in namespace 'Eigen::internal'
      return internal::rcond_estimate_helper(m_l1_norm, *this);
             ~~~~~~~~~~^
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Cholesky/LLT.h:535:36: error: out-of-line definition of 'llt' from class 'SelfAdjointView<MatrixType, Mode>' without definition
SelfAdjointView<MatrixType, UpLo>::llt() const
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Cholesky/LLT.h:537:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PlainObject'
  return LLT<PlainObject,UpLo>(m_matrix);
             ^
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:3:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Core:458:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:14:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/../../Eigen:1:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Dense:3:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Cholesky:33:
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Cholesky/LDLT.h:220:24: error: no member named 'rcond_estimate_helper' in namespace 'Eigen::internal'
      return internal::rcond_estimate_helper(m_l1_norm, *this);
             ~~~~~~~~~~^
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Cholesky/LDLT.h:654:36: error: out-of-line definition of 'ldlt' from class 'SelfAdjointView<MatrixType, Mode>' without definition
SelfAdjointView<MatrixType, UpLo>::ldlt() const
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Cholesky/LDLT.h:656:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PlainObject'
  return LDLT<PlainObject,UpLo>(m_matrix);
              ^
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:3:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Core:365:
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/util/ForwardDeclarations.h:121:63: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Eigen::Array<long, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1>'
         typename StrideType = typename internal::conditional<PlainObjectType::IsVectorAtCompileTime,InnerStride<1>,OuterStride<> >::type > class Ref;
                                                              ^
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/SVD/BDCSVD.h:101:11: note: in instantiation of default argument for 'Ref<Eigen::Array<long, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1>, 0>' required here
  typedef Ref<ArrayXi> IndicesRef;
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/util/ForwardDeclarations.h:242:60: note: template is declared here
         int _MaxRows = _Rows, int _MaxCols = _Cols> class Array;
                                                           ^
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:3:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Core:458:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:14:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/../../Eigen:1:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Dense:5:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/SVD:38:
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/SVD/BDCSVD.h:193:11: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Eigen::Array<long, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1>'
  ArrayXi m_workspaceI;
          ^
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/util/ForwardDeclarations.h:242:60: note: template is declared here
         int _MaxRows = _Rows, int _MaxCols = _Cols> class Array;
                                                           ^
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:3:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Core:458:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:14:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/../../Eigen:1:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Dense:5:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/SVD:38:
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/SVD/BDCSVD.h:599:16: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Eigen::Map<Eigen::Array<long, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >'
  Map<ArrayXi> perm(m_workspaceI.data(),m);
               ^
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/util/ForwardDeclarations.h:118:99: note: template is declared here
template<typename MatrixType, int MapOptions=Unaligned, typename StrideType = Stride<0,0> > class Map;
                                                                                                  ^
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:3:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Core:458:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:14:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/../../Eigen:1:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/Dense:5:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/SVD:38:
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/SVD/BDCSVD.h:694:17: error: member reference base type 'const IndicesRef' (aka 'const int') is not a structure or union
  Index m = perm.size();
            ~~~~^~~~~
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/SVD/BDCSVD.h:698:19: error: called object type 'IndicesRef' (aka 'int') is not a function or function pointer
    Index j = perm(i);
              ~~~~^
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/SVD/BDCSVD.h:901:17: error: member reference base type 'const IndicesRef' (aka 'const int') is not a structure or union
  Index m = perm.size();
            ~~~~^~~~~
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/SVD/BDCSVD.h:907:20: error: called object type 'IndicesRef' (aka 'int') is not a function or function pointer
  Index last = perm(m-1);
               ~~~~^
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/SVD/BDCSVD.h:921:23: error: called object type 'IndicesRef' (aka 'int') is not a function or function pointer
        Index i = perm(l);
                  ~~~~^
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/SVD/BDCSVD.h:924:35: error: called object type 'IndicesRef' (aka 'int') is not a function or function pointer
          Index j = i<k ? i : perm(l-1);
                              ~~~~^
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/SVD/BDCSVD.h:949:17: error: member reference base type 'const IndicesRef' (aka 'const int') is not a structure or union
  Index m = perm.size();
            ~~~~^~~~~
D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/SVD/BDCSVD.h:963:23: error: called object type 'IndicesRef' (aka 'int') is not a function or function pointer
        Index i = perm(l);
                  ~~~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

This is my first time trying to include an external library into my android project so this issue may be obvious  But I tried following the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317701/add-eigen-library-to-android-ndk).

I will attatch below the files that I think are relevant, if there is anything else you need please let me know.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             native-lib.cpp )

include_directories(src/main/cpp/Eigen)

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gpcsl.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**Native-lib.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include "Eigen/Core"

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_gpcsl_myapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env,jobject /* this */)
{
    Eigen::Matrix2d b;


    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

I've also noticed that If I actually open any of the Eigen src files that there is a lot of errors for example:[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvik7.png)

Comment: are you test on real device or emulator?

Comment: A real android device, Honor View 20

Comment: This demo helpful for you :https://github.com/kneth/EigenDemo

Comment: @ViralPatel Unfortunately I cannot get that link to work.  The instructions _After cloning, do git submodule upgrade --init --recursive to download Eigen._ causes an error (It appears to be because the submodual has been moved) and even after I change the submodual to point to the [new location](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git) it still gives the following error when trying to clone the eigen submodual I get the following error

`Cloning into 'E:/EigenDemo/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen'...no such remote ref 30994dce407e30c54191fa71ece4e6f70761b9bb`

Comment: What Eigen version are you using? Did you fiddle inside the Eigen sources? Your error message looks like `Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h` includes `Eigen/Eigen` which should not be the case.

Comment: @chtz I Just grabbed the latest [stable release](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/archive/3.3.7/eigen-3.3.7.zip) and I haven't edited anything

Comment: Can you show line 14 of your `D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h`? Your compiler output suggests that there is a `#include "../../Eigen"`, which should not be there.

Comment: Indeed, It looks like there `#include "../../Eigen"` on line 14 of Matrix.h

Comment: @chtz commenting out that line (Which thinking back I may have indeed added by accident) seems to fix the issue.  If you make an answer I wil accept and award the bounty

Comment: @chtz the bounty for this expires in two days, if you'd like the reward could you post an answer please

Comment: @AndrewRogers were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: @ahasbini yes it appears so, as chtz said I had modified the source and added an include where it shouldn't have been

Answer (score 2):

Do not include anything under the `Eigen/src/` directory. That is essentially the internal implementation. Instead of `#include "Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h"` you want to include `#include "Eigen/Core"` or `#include "Eigen/Dense"`.

Based on chtz's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59307786/add-eigen-to-android/59342899#comment105036283_59307786), the actual problem was that the internal implementation was modified by OP, which made the internal implementation include the exposed API. This was noticeable from the compiler errors:

```
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:14:
In file included from D:/newnativetest/app/src/main/cpp/Eigen/src/Core/../../Eigen:1:
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, However I've had already tried this and I get the same issue (In that it doesn't compile. However I will update my original answer to avoid confusion)